# ldconfig creating links with strange names after patching libraries with patchelf?

Tags: dynamic-linking, linker, ld, patchelf, ldconfig

I am patching several libraries on my development server to remove unneeded dependencies using the `patchelf` tool. These get packaged into an RPM and installed on my runtime system. After the install, `ldconfig` gets called, and strange links are created.

The locations of the patched libraries on the runtime system is something like `/usr1/blah/lib` and a few subfolders. This location and the location of the subfolders is specified in my `/etc/ld.so.conf` file. When I run `ldconfig`, a bunch of links with strange names are created, such as:

`?N -> libFoo.so`

`??r? -> libBar.so`

as well as links whose names are partial function names of functions in the library, e.g. if I do `objdump -x` and look at the function names, the link will have part of that function as its name.

My understanding was that ldconfig looks at the `SONAME` of the libraries and creates a link with that name. However when I do an `objdump -x` on all the affected libraries and grep for `SONAME`, nothing is out of the ordinary, they all end in .so and have none of the weird question marks.

`ldconfig -v` provides no helpful information.

Any ideas as to what could be going on? Maybe the `SONAME` is getting screwed up in some way that I'm missing? Thanks for any help.

edit: if I merely remove dependencies as a part of my patching process (e.g. only call `patchelf --remove-needed <dependency> <lib name>`, then this issue doesn't happen. it's only when I use the `--add-needed` flag.

edit 2: If I just add and remove a garbage dependency (e.g. `patchelf --add-needed garbage libFoo.so` followed immediately by `patchelf --remove-needed garbage libFoo.so`), that causes the weird link issue as well. The final dependency list in each library is the exact same, and it works when I just use the `--remove-needed` flag, which leads me to think that the issue is the `--add-needed` flag and whatever `patchelf` does to the header when it does that.

edit 3: at this point I am going with the assumption that this is a bug with either patchelf or ldconfig. I'm guessing it's the latter since we're using `glibc` version 2.17 which is from ~2012, but the latest version of `patchelf`. perhaps the ELF standard has changed.

tl;dr with patchelf version 0.10 and glibc version 2.17, the --add-needed option appears to mess with the ELF such that ldconfig is creating some wonky links.

Answer (score 0):

`ldconfig` is not just smart enough to properly read the ELF format after changing some section (particularly, adding/changing/removing soname or rpath).

The library itself can be totally OK though, it is just the `ldconfig` problem.